# Limit substitution in integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I want to integrate

$$
\frac{1}{v}(v^2-c_s^2)\frac{dv}{dr} = 2c_s^2[\frac{r-r_c}{r^2}]
$$

to end up with:

$$
(\frac{v}{c_s})^2 - \ln(\frac{v}{c_s})^2 = 4\ln(\frac{r}{r_c})+4\frac{r_c}{r}+C
$$

But I'm stuck at:

$$
\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - 2\ln(v)=4\frac{r_c}{r}-4\ln(r)
$$

Do I need to sub in limits? If so what will they be?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - 2\ln(v)=4\frac{r_c}{r}+4\ln(r)+\tilde{C}
$$

Notice your integration was missing some constant additon (because differentiation will kill this constant). I've added $\tilde{C}$ to be this constant. I've also corrected an obvious sign error in your solution. Now, let

$$\tilde{C}=-4\ln(r_c)-2\ln(c_s)+C$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Substituting this in we have

$$\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - 2\ln(v)=4\frac{r_c}{r}+4\ln(r)-4\ln(r_c)-2\ln(c_s)+C
$$

Bringing $2\ln (c_s)$ to the other side and grouping some terms we have
$$\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - 2\left(\ln(v)-\ln(c_s)\right)=4\frac{r_c}{r}+4\left(\ln(r)-\ln(r_c)\right)+C
$$

From our Laws of Logarithms we remember this is

$$\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - 2\left(\ln\left(\frac{v}{c_s}\right)\right)=4\frac{r_c}{r}+4\left(\ln\left(\frac{r}{r_c}\right)\right)+C
$$

Which, by another Law of Logarithms, is

$$\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - \left(\ln\left(\frac{v}{c_s}\right)^2\right)=4\frac{r_c}{r}+4\left(\ln\left(\frac{r}{r_c}\right)\right)+C
$$

Dropping unnecessary brackets:

$$\frac{v^2}{c_s^2} - \ln\left(\frac{v}{c_s}\right)^2=4\frac{r_c}{r}+4\ln\left(\frac{r}{r_c}\right)+C
$$

Which is exactly what you needed. In summary: you were missing a $+C$.

Comment: Thank you. Just one quick question: how did you make $$\tilde{C}=-4\ln(r_c)-2\ln(c_s)+C$$?

Comment: $\tilde{C}$ is also just a constant: there is only one independent variable here, $r$. Thus, $r_c$ and $c_s$ must also be constant values, so we're allowed to choose the constant $\tilde{C}$ to write our final answer in whichever way that we want.